# GetType on System.Web.UI.Page in ASP.NET - returns different namespace and name

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.Net and GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202073/asp-net-and-gettype)

I ran into a slight problem today.

As you can see from the code below, I have an ASP.NET Page called "Users" in the namespace "WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure".

If I do a "this.GetType()" I get a different .FullName than I expect as seen below:

```
namespace WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure
{
    [tWorks.Core.CoreCommons.Attributes.Security("CREATEUSER", "Anger säkerhetsklass för att skapa användare")] 
    public partial class Users : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         Type t = this.GetType();
         Console.WriteLine(t.FullName); // "ASP.secure_views_users_aspx"
    }
```

So, instead of getting "WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure.Users" I get "ASP.secure_views_users_aspx".

Why? Is there any way to retrieve "WebApplicationExtNetTest.Secure.Users" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answers to this question: [ASP.Net and GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202073/asp-net-and-gettype)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Weird, I searched SO and looked through the suggestions - didnt find that answer =(

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an ASP.NET page is simply the source code for a new compiled version, that is done behind the scene when the first request is made.

So your page becomes the base class for a new derived class that is executed when a user request a page.

That's why you get a different type when calling GetType() function.

The answer that Simen pointed has a way to get the original type programmatically.

However, if you're using ASP.NET MVC things are a bit different, bu the principle remains the same.